# Which Maven plugin downloads maven dependencies?

Tags: maven

Is Maven dependencies handling (i.e. download) done via a plugin?

Is Maven using dependency plugin undercover (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/)?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Could you give us more background information?

Comment: I'm trying to understand how does it work.

Comment: Ok, I just thought there might be a concrete problem behind this abstract question.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, Maven is using the dependency plugin to download dependencies.**

You can have a look at the [dependency:get](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html) docs or even the [GetMojo source code](https://github.com/apache/maven-dependency-plugin/blob/a0ac6fedf87dec9ec3ca93dd83d28ef2828cb544/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/dependency/GetMojo.java) for further detail.

Comment: I suppose so, but couldn't find any documentation on this. They didn't state anywhere that <dependencies> section is used by this plugin undercover, which I would expect.

Answer (score 0):

I might be very late to answer this question but here is the maven plugin which is responsible to download all dependencies. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/

You can read more about all plugins here on this page (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html)